# Can GLMNet perform Logistic regression?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glmnet

I am using GLMNet to perform LASSO on Binary Logistic models with cv.GLMNet to test selection consistency and would like to compare its performance with plain GLM Logistic regression. For fairness' sake in comparing the outputs, I would like to use GLMNet to perform this regression, however, I am unable to find any way to do so, barring using GLMnet with alpha = 0 and Lambda = 0 (Ridge without a penalty factor). However, I am unsure about this method, as it seems slightly janky, GLMnet's manual discourages the inputting of single lambda values (for speed reasons) and it provides me no z-values to determine the confidence level of the coefficient. (Essentially, the ideal output would be something similar to just using r's GLM function)

I've read through the entire manual and cant find a method of doing this, is there a way to perform Logistic Regression with GLMNet, without the penalty factor in order to get an output similar to r's GLM?

Comment: Best I can think of is setting `penalty.factor=rep(0,nvars)` and `nlambda=1`. You can think of `penalty.factor[i]` as being an additional penalization on feature i, so that the regularization parameter is `lambda * penalty.factor[i]` for feature i. From my understanding of the low-level routine, if the algorithm generates `lambda` sequence, the first one always fits only the variables that are unpenalized. But as you said, this is kind of janky.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.